# SSL Intermediate SHA2

Tags: ssl, mobile, certificate, ssl-certificate

I've installed a SSL certificate on my Website, but the `intermediate.crt` isn't working.
Any SSL Checker (e.g. GeoTrust Checker) told me, that an intermediate key is missing.
On the website a SSL certificate was already in use, only the switch from `SHA1` to `SHA2` is new.

**I use this structure:**

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> (Secondary Intermediate Certificate)
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> (Primary Intermediate Certificate)
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> (Root certificate)
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Who has an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

It was the wrong reference to the intermediate